# How to change the entry of a MultiIndex columns pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` such that `df.columns` returns

```
   MultiIndex([( 'a', 's1', 'm/s'),
            ( 'a', 's2',   '%'),
            ( 'a', 's3',  '°C'),
            ('b', 'z3',  '°C'),
            ('b', 'z4', 'kPa')],
           names=['kind', 'names', 'units'])
```

How to change ONLY the column name `('b', 'z3',  '°C')` into `('b', 'z3',  'degC')`?

At the moment I am trying the following

```
        old_cols_name = ('b', 'z3',  '°C')
        new_cols_name = list(old_cols_name)
        new_cols_name[2] = "degC"
        df = df_temp.rename(
            columns={old_cols_name: new_cols_name},
        )
```

But it does not work in the sense that the columns names of `df` are left unchanged.

EDIT: Question slightly changed to add more generality.

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify a `MultiIndex`, so you will have to recreate it.

An handy way might be to transform back and forth to `DataFrame`.

Assuming `idx` the MultiIndex:

```
new_idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(idx.to_frame().replace('°C', 'degC'))
```

Or use the DataFrame constructor:

```
new_idx = pd.DataFrame(index=idx).rename({'°C': 'degC'}).index
```

Note that you can limit to a given level with:

```
new_idx = pd.Series(index=idx).rename({'°C': 'degC'}, level='units').index
```

Output:

```
MultiIndex([('a', 's1',  'm/s'),
            ('a', 's2',    '%'),
            ('a', 's3', 'degC'),
            ('b', 'z3', 'degC'),
            ('b', 'z4',  'kPa')],
           names=['kind', 'names', 'units'])
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am going to edit my original question as I need something more general. Please, consider update your reply.

Answer (score 1):

I believe changing the desired column alone would work:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(columns= pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([( 'a', 's1', 'm/s'),
               ( 'a', 's2',   '%'),
               ( 'a', 's3',  'degC'),
               ('b', 'z3',  '°C'),
               ('b', 'z4', 'kPa')],
           names=['kind', 'names', 'units']))
```

```
MultiIndex([('a', 's1',  'm/s'),
            ('a', 's2',    '%'),
            ('a', 's3', 'degC'),
            ('b', 'z3',   '°C'),
            ('b', 'z4',  'kPa')],
           names=['kind', 'names', 'units'])
```

using:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'°C': 'degC'}, level=2)
```

```
MultiIndex([('a', 's1',  'm/s'),
            ('a', 's2',    '%'),
            ('a', 's3', 'degC'),
            ('b', 'z3', 'degC'),
            ('b', 'z4',  'kPa')],
           names=['kind', 'names', 'units'])
```

In the edited question you mentioned you only want to change one of the '°C' to 'degC'. This is not possible as in MultiIndex the two '°C' are considered as **the same label**. Essentially the structure of the MultiIndex would need to be changed, instead of just a name change. To do that you have to reconstruct the MultiIndex:

```
new_idx = df.columns.to_numpy()
new_idx[3] = ('b', 'z3',  'degC')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(new_idx, names = df.columns.names)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I am going to edit my original question as I need something more general. Please, consider update your reply.

Comment: see the updated. I think MultiIndex is not designed for this kind of manipulation, which is probably why there is no easy solution.

Comment: Yes, I got the same feeling. Another alternative that I found is to use to_flat_index() and replace the whole tuple representing the column name that you want to change. 
But then you have to recreate the MultiIndex anyway with the from_tuples() method. If you are using a reference (as I usually do) to keep code readability, then during the various steps you should pay attention to when you got a Dataframe copy or a DataFrame view as return of a function call. Gosh, I am afraid of a maintenance nightmare in the future!